# Finding the Length of a Line Segment that Starts From the Origin and Ends at a Line Tangential to the Unit Circle

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to finding the length of a line segment that starts from the origin and ends at a line tangential to the unit circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a line segment from the center of the circle to the point of tangency, we get a right triangle OAB.

[image: figure with extra auxiliary line]

Based on the angles you gave, it should be an isosceles right triangle, and one of the legs is a radius of the circle.  Does that help?